# ¿Como puedo obtener el archivo que se ha pasado en un formulario con un input type file?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario que recoge unos datos y un archivo. Al cambiar de página, ¿existe alguna manera de guardar ese archivo y recogerlo en otro .js?

Es decir, si tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<form name="mainForm" id="mainForm" onsubmit="return ValidationEvent()">
            <label for="fileName">Fichero:</label>
            <input type="file" id="fileName" name="fileName" value="">
            <br>
            <label for="pathDestino">Destino:</label>
            <input type="text" id="pathDestino" name="pathDestino" value="">
            <br>
            <label for="dataSelected">Fecha:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dataSelected" name="dataSelected" value="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="btSubmitMainForm" name="btSubmitMainForm" value="ACEPTAR">
            <input hidden name="opc" value="data">
            <input hidden name="index" value="-1">
            <div class="errorMsgMainForm" id="errorMsgMainForm" hidden>
                <p>⚠️ Comprueba de que todos los<br> campos sean correctos</p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Ahora, una vez seleccionado el archivo, ¿como lo puedo obtener en un .js? ¿Puedo pasarlo de un .js a otro mediante export?

Comment: Esta respuesta te puede ayudar, la clave esta en crear un FileReader y pasarle `input.files[0]` al file reader. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282163/6032155

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza me lo miro! A ver si me sirve. Muchas gracias!